# How is the site context language determined and is there a priority to which is chosen?

Tags: multilingual

The other day a colleague was asking about the **sc_lang** query string parameter and how Sitecore knows to use that for the language. The conversation was seeking answers to the following questions:

- What are all the ways in which Sitecore determines which language to use?
- What is the order of priority for each method in relation to the other?
- Is there a way to include other procedures to determine the language?

Comment: Hey Michael have you checked this post? 
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-overriding-sitecore-39-s-logic-to-determine-the-context-language

Comment: Thank you. No I've not seen that article. Does it still hold true for Sitecore 9?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. It was valid for previous versions though

Comment: Nothing in the release notes suggest that this part of the codebase has changed in any way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is well covered on [John West's post](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-overriding-sitecore-39-s-logic-to-determine-the-context-language) which in summary describes what the priority is and how Sitecore handles them:

"The Sitecore layout engine retrieves content from the Sitecore repository in the context language (Sitecore.Context.Language). The default logic to determine the context language is to use the first of these variables that specifies a value:

1. The **sc_lang** query string parameter.

   > https://www.company.com/about-us/?sc_lang=en
2. The **language prefix** in the path in the requested URL.

   > https://www.company.com/en/about-us/
3. The **language cookie** associated with the context site.

   > company#lang
4. The **default language** associated with the **context logical site**.

```xml
<site name="company" patch:before="site[@name='website']" 
    virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/company" language="en" 
    hostName="www.company.com" />
```

5. The **DefaultLanguage** setting specified in web.config.

```xml
<setting name="DefaultLanguage" value="en" />
```

#### References:

- [Community Site - John West](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-overriding-sitecore-39-s-logic-to-determine-the-context-language)
- [Sitecore Corner](https://sitecorecorner.wordpress.com/2017/05/15/sitecore-context-language/)