# Sitecore Multidomain Similar Language possible?

Tags: multilingual, multisite, site-configuration

We have implemented multisite & multilingual Sitecore implementation and now we are going to implement new website which will support 4 languages. 
Sitecore8.1 in use.
Code base( VS solution) & Sitecore instance is common for all these sites.

Existing sites

```
  <!--Site-1: US-->
        <site name="site1-us"
        hostName="www.site1.com"
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        language="en" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
        startItem="/" 
        database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
        cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
        htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
        enableTracking="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="true" 
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        linkProvider="languageEmbedded"
        itemwebapi.mode="Off"
        itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
        itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
        patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
                    pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>


      <!--Site-1: UK-->
        <site name="site1-uk"
        hostName="www.site1.com"
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        language="en-GB" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
        startItem="/" 
        database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
        cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
        htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
        enableTracking="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="true" 
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        linkProvider="languageEmbedded"
        itemwebapi.mode="Off"
        itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
        itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
        patch:after="site[@name='site1-us']"
                    pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>

      <!--Site-1: AU-->
        <site name="site1-au"
        hostName="www.site1.com"
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        language="en-AU" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
        startItem="/" 
        database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
        cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
        htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
        enableTracking="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="true" 
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        linkProvider="languageEmbedded"
        itemwebapi.mode="Off"
        itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
        itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
        patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
                    pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>


      <!--Site-1: CA-->
        <site name="site1-ca"
        hostName="www.site1.com"
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        language="en-CA" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
        startItem="/" 
        database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
        cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
        htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
        enableTracking="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="true" 
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        linkProvider="languageEmbedded"
        itemwebapi.mode="Off"
        itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
        itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
        patch:after="site[@name='site1-us']"
                    pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>
```

URL: http://www.site1.com/en http://www.site1.com/en-GB http://www.site1.com/en-AU http://www.site1.com/en-CA

```
      <!--Site-2: en-IE-->
        <site name="site2"
        hostName="www.site2.com"
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        language="en-IE" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site2" 
        startItem="/" 
        database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
        cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
        htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
        enableTracking="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="true" 
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        itemwebapi.mode="Off"
        itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
        itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
        patch:before="site[@name='site1-us']"
                    pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>


      <!--Site-2: en-TT-->
        <site name="site2-tt"
        hostName="www.site2.com"
        virtualFolder="/" 
        physicalFolder="/" 
        language="en-TT" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site2" 
        startItem="/" 
        database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
        domain="extranet" 
        allowDebug="true" 
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
        cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
        htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
        registryCacheSize="0" 
        viewStateCacheSize="0" 
        xslCacheSize="5MB" 
        filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
        enablePreview="true" 
        enableWebEdit="true" 
        enableDebugger="true" 
        removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
        enableTracking="true"
        disableClientData="false"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="true" 
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        itemwebapi.mode="Off"
        itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
        itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
        patch:after="site[@name='site1-us']"
                    pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>
```

URL: http://www.site2.com (Language embedding is not there for this site)

rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site3" startItem="/" --> This support one language en-NZ.

URL: http://www.site3.com

New WebSite

```
<!--Site4 - US-->
    <site name="site4-us"
            hostname="www.site4.com"
                virtualFolder="/" 
                physicalFolder="/" 
                language="en" 
                rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site4" 
                startItem="/" 
                database="${Sites.WebDatabase}"
                domain="extranet" 
                allowDebug="true" 
                loginPage="/profile/login.aspx" 
                cacheHtml="${Sites.CacheHtml}" 
                htmlCacheSize="1000MB" 
                registryCacheSize="0" 
                viewStateCacheSize="0" 
                xslCacheSize="5MB" 
                filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" 
                enablePreview="true" 
                enableWebEdit="true" 
                enableDebugger="true" 
                removeTrailingSlashes ="true"
                enableTracking="true"
                disableClientData="false"
                enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
                enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
                Favicon="" 
                Custom="true"
                itemwebapi.mode="Off"
                itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly"
                itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false"
                patch:after="site[@name='site1-us']"
                pagesToRedirect="/experience"/>
```

URL: http://www.site4.com/en http://www.site4.com/en-GB http://www.site4.com/en-AU http://www.site4.com/en-CA

Is it possible to have this configuration possible?
I added the above site4 in sites.config, but since the languages are similar to Site1.
Now depending on how I patch it,
 --> patch:after="site[@name='site1']" , Site1 is rendered for both Site1 and Site4
 --> patch:before="site[@name='site1']" , Site4 is rendered for both Site1 and Site4.

Are there any suggestions for the above issue? Is it possible to have multi-domain sites but with same languages?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, your patching is incorrect. Update your question and share the config patches that you are using.

Comment: @jammykam: I've added the patches now and updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configs are very messy and repetitive, this makes them somewhat more difficult to work with. You can clean them up by [making use of the `inherits` property](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.ca/2014/08/inheriting-sitecore-site-properties.html) and setting some "defaults" on a base site config. You can then "override" the setting on your specific site entry.

You have also defined the same site multiple times, only changing the `language` attribute on each repetition... you don't need to do this, you only need to define the site once and *set the default language* for the site. Sitecore does not care about the [language per site](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/prevent-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms-from-interpreting-url-path-prefixes-as-language-names), it will [always try to resolve it](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/how-is-the-site-context-language-determined-and-is-there-a-priority-to-which-is) and return content on that language, instead it cares about the request domain name and trying to match that to the `hostName` attribute. Your code should handle generation of the links to switch language.

A sample config for multi-site resolving is as follows:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">>
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site
        name="website"
        Favicon="" 
        Custom="true"
        pagesToRedirect="/experience"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="True"
        loginPage="/profile/login.aspx"
        enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
        enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
        removeTrailingSlashes="true" />

      <site 
        name="site1"
        inherits="website"
        hostName="www.site1.com"
        language="en" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
        startItem="/" 
        linkProvider="languageEmbedded"
        patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']" />

      <site name="site2"
        hostName="www.site2.com"
        inherits="website"
        language="en-IE" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site2" 
        startItem="/" 
        patch:after="site[@name='site1']"/>

      <site name="site3"
        hostName="www.site3.com"
        inherits="website"
        language="en-NZ" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site3" 
        startItem="/" 
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="False"
        patch:after="site[@name='site1']"/>

      <site name="site4"
        hostName="www.site4.com"
        inherits="website"
        language="en" 
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site4" 
        startItem="/"
        linkProvider="languageEmbedded"
        EnableGeoIPSiteResolver="False"
        patch:after="site[@name='site1']"/>
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

For ease of inheritance, I've define the base site as `website` and added the custom attributes to this site (from your config), and the defined each site **only once** setting the default language to serve content if none is specified (or the language cookie is not set). Each site can also override any attributes from the base site definition.

If you have a separate config per site then split the above config up as required, the config for each site remains the same and unchanged.

Comment: Thank you @jammykam, I'm working on trying your suggestions and will update this once it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around is the language fallback feature that can cater this requirement.

check this, it will work like this.

[image]

for complete documentation, follow this reference link

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/language_fallback/language_fallback

Answer (score 0):

I have found one scenario where I did have to define the site more than once for each language, and that is if they share the same starting item but have different hostNames. This was necessary so that SiteResolving in the Link Provider worked properly. For example:

```
<site name="site1"
    inherits="website"
    hostName="www.site1.com"
    language="en" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
    startItem="/" 
    patch:before="site[@name='website']" />
<site name="site1ES"
    inherits="website"
    hostName="www.site1.com"
    language="es" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
    startItem="/" 
    patch:before="site[@name='website']" />
<site name="site1CA"
    hostName="ca.site1.com"
    inherits="website"
    language="en-CA" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
    startItem="/" 
    patch:before="site[@name='website']" />
<site name="site1CAFR"
    hostName="ca.site1.com"
    inherits="website"
    language="fr-CA" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1" 
    startItem="/" 
    patch:before="site[@name='website']" />
```

However, this can easily be avoided by having a different starting path for each domain.

Comment: The above can be compacted down to 2 `<site>` entries, `site1ES` and `site1CAFR` would never actual match.

Comment: Cross-site links did not render properly in this scenario without the extra site definitions. Instead it rendered the links as www.site1.com/fr-ca for example, when we need it to be ca.site1.com/fr-ca. This is in Sitecore 8.2.

Comment: Sure, but I stated you could remove the additional language sites (`site1ES` and `site1CAFR`), not `site1CA` which would be required for the subdomain.

Comment: Without those extras, the other languages did not render to the appropriate subdomain. site1CA handled en-CA, but it didn't know where fr-CA should go so it would end up www.site1.com/fr-ca instead of ca.site1.com/fr-ca like we wanted it. This was only an issue because we had the same tree for multiple subdomains and languages.

Comment: AFAIK Sitecore does not take the language into account when resolving a site, the `LanguageResolver` is a separate pipeline processor. Maybe you had something custom or a different issue, but OOTB I have never needed to duplicate site configs like this on any of the multilingual sites I have ever worked on.

Comment: I had never had this problem either until we switched to sharing one content tree for multiple subdomains. Not sure if it's a combination of settings or what, but having the extra definitions is how we fixed it.