# Setting site default language in SXA

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I'm using Sitecore 9 and SXA 1.7.

I can set the default language of the site at Site Grouping:

[image]

I want to know where to set the language programmatically in SXA.
Which dll to use, as I want to override this behavior?

Comment: Are you trying to just change Context Language? Why do you need to change language on site programatically?

Comment: I saved the user's last opened language, I want the site to be opened in the user's last language when the browser is closed and opened again, so I want to set the language from the SXA pipeline, as when I set it using jquery cookies, the performance was poor.

Comment: I think that setting Language cookie (3rd option from answer to this question https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/how-is-the-site-context-language-determined-and-is-there-a-priority-to-which-is) would be best solution for what you are trying to achieve. This has nothing to do with SXA. This is general Sitecore topic

Answer (score 1):

In SXA you don't need it to set it programmatically. SXA is designed with zero code approach, and almost everything is possible without editing the code.

for DLLm Check the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite`

Before you create a new Website in Tenant, just add the new language you desire, for example Arabic. Go to `/sitecore/system/Languages/' and add the new language

[image]

Select Arabic and proceed till completion.

[image]

Once added, Go to your tenant, and create a new Site, There you will see the language you just created.

[image]

Comment: I know that, I want to know where this process is made pro grammatically, as I need to override this due to my business needs.

Comment: Check the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite` dll

Comment: I thought of it too, I decompiled it but it has many classes, if you know which method please tell me.

Comment: You can set default language in your config `<setting name="DefaultLanguage" value="en" />`
check this answer, it will help https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/how-is-the-site-context-language-determined-and-is-there-a-priority-to-which-is?noredirect=1&lq=1